# how to sort csv file with python to progressively add rows of data to output

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm a Python newbie trying to write a script to help my wife with a work project.  She needs to be able to enter a sentence and have it build one word at a time over multiple lines.  I can make this code work with CSV if I know how many words total there will be and I hard code that into the script.  How would I do this if the total number of words is not known. My thought was to get the length of the string and then iterate over it but I can't figure out the logic.

```
import csv
with open('csvtest.csv')as csvfile:
    readCSV=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')

    for row in readCSV:
        print(row)
        print (row[0],row[1])
        print (row[0],row[1],row[2])
        print (row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3])
        print (row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4])
```

Comment: what is this functionality for? also you can try `for row in readCSV: for word in row.split(' ')` but it's hard to tell exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
s = "This is my test string"
words = s.split()

for i in range(0,len(words)): 
    for j in range(0,i+1):
        print(words[j]),  # add comma after print statement to not enforce newline
    print  # print newline here
```

which produces an output of:

```
This
This is
This is my
This is my test
This is my test string
```

This works for any arbitrary length string `s` which helps to solve your problem of not knowing beforehand the length of your input string. As long as you split it by the words you can iterate over it as a list of those words which are contained within the input string.

Comment: Looks like this is the answer i needed. I had tried split string but couldnt get the progressive build of output. I think the comma after the print statement is what i missed. Look forward to trying this and comparing it to my earlier attempts.  Thank you aus_lacy!

Comment: @LDH2nd No problem. With stack overflow if an answer is useful in finding a solution or is the accepted answer for your question then it should be up-voted and/or accepted as the correct answer so that future users of SO who may have a similar question to yours can quickly find a solution and avoid wasting time searching aimlessly. You can up-vote with the arrows in the upper left hand corner of the solution and accept the answer by clicking the checkmark located under the up/down vote buttons.

Comment: I just realized I am trying to write this in Python 3.x and the trailing comma doesn't work. Is there a way to do the same thing in Python 3?

Comment: @LDH2nd try `print(word[j], end="")`